# Incrementing an event listener event to listen to a specific id (card-1, card-2, card-3 etc...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem**

I am building a slide show. When I move to the next slide I increment my card-id  like this:

```
cardId++;
$('#card-' + (cardId)).show();
```

I also have another on keyup listener... I want trigger a function when someone enters text into an input field with the class 'blank-input' where that input is within a div with the card id (card-1, card-2, card-3 etc...).

**My code:**

the markup (I am looping through my cards from a database)

```
<!-- lesson cards -->
<?php $card_id = 2; ?>
<?php foreach ($cards as $card) : ?>
<div id="card-<?php echo $card_id; ?>" class="container-fluid card-container" style="background:#eaeaec;display:none;">

    <span id="cardId" class="animated fadeInDown"><?php echo $card_id; ?></span>

    <!-- card template one -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 animated fadeInLeft" id="leftContent-<?php echo $card_id; ?>">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $card->card_name; ?>
                <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
            </h2>
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($card->card_html); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 animated fadeInRight" id="rightContent-<?php echo $card_id; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url($card->file_path); ?>" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end card template one -->

</div>
<?php $card_id++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- end lesson cards -->
```

My script

```
$(function(){

    if (window.location.hash == '') {
        var cardId = 1;
    } else {
        var cardId = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    }

    showCard(); // first thing that is run

    /**
     * first function to run
     */
    function showCard(){
        $('#card-' + (cardId)).show();
    }

    $('#nextCard').click(function(){
        if ($('#card-' + (cardId + 1)).length != 0) {  // if there is a next card
            $('#card-' + (cardId)).hide();             // hide current card
            cardId++;                                  // increment the card id
            $('#card-' + (cardId)).show();             // and show the next card
            location.hash = cardId;
        }
    });

    $('#previousCard').click(function(){
        if (cardId != 1) {                 // if we are not at the first card
            $('#card-' + (cardId)).hide(); // hide the current card
            cardId--;                      // decrement the card id
            $('#card-' + (cardId)).show(); // and show the previous card
            location.hash = cardId;
        }
    });

    /**
     * fill in the blank
     */
    blanks = document.getElementsByClassName('blank');
    for(i = 0; i < blanks.length; i++){
        $(blanks[i]).html(
            '<input class="blank-input" data="' + $(blanks[i]).html()  + '"></input>'
        );
    }
    $('#card-' + (cardId)).on('keyup', '.blank-input', function(){
        this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 12) + 'px';
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data')) {
            $(this).removeClass('blank-incorrect').addClass('blank-correct animated tada');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('blank-correct').addClass('blank-incorrect');
        }
    });    
});
```

**Question:**

How do I update my 'keyup' event listener to listen to inputs that are in the `id` that is showing, e.g. card-1, card-2 etc...

Comment: Can you please add your html code..? if possible thn add fildder also

Comment: Edited my OP, I am echoing a lot of data through php... for each card that I am looping through I am adding a new div with the next card id, card-1, card-2 etc.

Comment: Just make a class and bind the keyup event to that class

Comment: Does your `card-??` elements get created dynamically or are they there since the document loaded?

Comment: Hi ibraham, answer below solved my problem, I was overcomplicating things!

Comment: I think the problem was to do with the scope of the variables, I was declaring them inside the functions but couldn't access them outside those functions... the answer below removed the whole basis of that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ids to a class, remove the event from the loop:

```
$('.card-container').on('keyup', '.blank-input', function(){
        this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 12) + 'px';
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data')) {
            $(this).removeClass('blank-incorrect').addClass('blank-correct animated tada');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('blank-correct').addClass('blank-incorrect');
        }
    });
```

Note: the blank class doesn't exist on the html provided so the appending of the html will not work, choose a different selector for it

Comment: I am storing that HTML inside of a database so it is there on page load... anyway thanks for solving this problem in such an simple way!